# Can someone tell me why am I getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error in my code?

Tags: java, loops, exception, ioexception, thread-exceptions

I am working on a Java program to iterate through two arrays and compare the first one to the second for any matches. It should return all the numbers/strings that DON'T MATCH as an array list. I am done, but I am not sure why I am getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` **error**. This is my code:

```
package test;

import java.awt.List;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayComparer {
    public static ArrayList<String> ArrayComparer(String[] arrayOne, String[] arrayTwo){
//      if one is bigger than start by comparing the smaller one to the bigger one
//      as if it were the other way the bigger one would run out over numbers to compare
        
//      declaring the array for holding all the non-matching telephone numbers to be returned
         ArrayList<String> nonMatchingTelephoneNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int i = 0; i<arrayOne.length; i++){
            int strikes = 0;
//          for each value of the first one it should go through all the values of the second and compare each
            for(int i2 = 0; i<arrayTwo.length; i2++){
                if(arrayOne[i] != arrayTwo[i2]){
                    strikes++;
                    if(strikes == arrayTwo.length){
//                      meaning it has gone through ALL of arrayTwo and couldn't find a match
                        nonMatchingTelephoneNumbers.add(arrayOne[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
                
        }
        return nonMatchingTelephoneNumbers;
        
        
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
//          declaring the first list of telephone number
        String[] ArrayListOne;
//          declaring the second list of telephone numbers
        String[] ArrayListTwo;
//      splitting up the user input of telephone numbers by commas
        
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
        System.out.println("Enter your first array of telephone numbers, split by commas");
        
        ArrayListOne = myObj.nextLine().split(",");  // Read user input
        
     
//      once it has iterated through all of the telephone numbers in the first list, ask for the second list
        Scanner myObj2 = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
        System.out.println("Enter your second array of telephone numbers, split by commas");
        
        ArrayListTwo = myObj2.nextLine().split(",");  // Read the second user input

//      once it has collected and sorted all the user input, the ArrayCOmparer method should be called 
//      to compare them and return the telephone numbers that DON'T MATCH
        
        ArrayComparer(ArrayListOne, ArrayListTwo);
        
    }

}
```

The error is on **line 22**, where it says `if(arrayOne[i] != arrayTwo[i2]){`.It also doesn't say there is an **error on line 22** until I run it. Can someone please tell me why I am getting this:[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsKa8.png)?

Comment: Why don't you post the relevant code here so people can assist you. No one wants to take the extra step of using Google Drive.

Comment: Oh ok sorry I will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i think this is causing the error

```
        for(int i2 = 0; i<arrayTwo.length; i2++){
```

You should replace it with:

```
        for(int i2 = 0; i2<arrayTwo.length; i2++){
```

Comment: Yeah, it was a silly mistake on my side! Thank you!